# PanedWindow Sash Attributes and Style

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble getting and setting the sash of my panedwindow widget.

My understanding is that I can read the current sash position so I can restore it upon the next start up. My main goal is to be able to read the current sash pos so I can restore it from a file. I can do the file part OK. I just can't seem to read the pos value and set a different value using sashpos(0,n).

I have print(panedwindow.sashpos(0)) which returns 0 but I'm not sure what that means?

When I create my panedwindow, if I try to use the sashrelief and sashpad attributes I get errors.

Also I'd like to style the sash (like sashthickness) but I can't get any of the style attributes to work without giving errors.

Thank you for any help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry('800x500-300+350')

# https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/panedwindow.html
panedwindow = ttk.Panedwindow(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)#, showhandle=TRUE, sashrelief=FLAT, sashpad=20)
panedwindow.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(panedwindow, relief=GROOVE, padding=5)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(panedwindow, relief=GROOVE, padding=5)

panedwindow.add(frame1, weight=1)
panedwindow.add(frame2, weight=4)

print(panedwindow.sashpos(0))
panedwindow.sashpos(0, 5)
#panedwindow.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tk.PanedWindow` accepts the `showhandle`, `sashrelief` and `sashpad` key words. `ttk.PanedWindow` (same as `ttk.Panedwindow`) doesn't accept those key words.

Comment: If you move the `panedwindow.update()` before the `panedwindow.sashpos(0)`, it prints the correct value.

Comment: _"I can't get any of the style attributes to work without giving errors."_ - please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I needed to be using tk. I switched over to tk and the attributes I'm interested in are now working. Thank you very much.